# How to disply only mp4 files in the browser using nodejs local streaming server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, video-streaming

I am trying to stream local video into web browser (chrome) and I used below code to stream local files

server.js

```
var walk    = require('walk');
const app = express()
const port = 3000;
const ipaddr = "localhost";

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
const videoHomeDir = os.homedir() + `/Videos`;
var files   = [];

var walker  = walk.walk(videoHomeDir, { followLinks: false });

walker.on('file', function(root, stat, next) {
    files.push(root + '/' + stat.name);
    next();
});

walker.on('end', function() {
    console.log("GOT ALL VIDEOS")
});
```

and code works file.

but problem was it display all file in the folder ( mp4 , txt , jpg ... ) but i expect only " Mp4 " files only.

How to display  video files only on browser using node js local media streaming.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can specify allowed extensions with walk?

otherwise you could only push the filename if the extension matches like:

```
if (stat.name.match('.mp4')) {
  files.push(root + '/' + stat.name);
}
```